# Why is my intent repeated when user responded it once? User must respond it again and then only will the following intent follow up

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am currently using webhook to call upon each intent after the user has responded to flow of my intents. I am however facing some issues where the user would have to repeat his/her response twice before it proceeds to the next intent. I am not doing anything complicated, my processes are like such

1) Create followup intent (this will automatically link the previous intent) 
[intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX6KI.png)

2) create a @sys.any for user to respond 
[@sys.any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztuM.png)

3) in training mode: I just type 'user input here' and link it to the value 
[training phrases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaYu7.png)

4) enable webhook
[webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gs9.png)

Regardless of all these, i have some intents that user would need to repeat twice. I don't have any other issues with previous intents, just two of them.
[simulator example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIYxB.png)

I tried deleting the intent and create a new followup but problem still persist.

//no problem with this intent, user respond once and it will go to the next one

```
 app.intent('questionrespond', (conv, params) => {
  conv.data.positivethinking = params.questionrespond;
  conv.ask(`<speak> <voice gender ="male" variant= "1"> oh <break 
  time="0.5s"/>  so what you are trying to say is <break 
  time="0.5s"/> by thinking of ${conv.data.positivethinking} may 
  <break time="0.3s"/> and may not increase positive thinking for 
  you <break time="0.7s"/> <p> okay <break time="0.7s"/> <s> I am 
  curious <break time="0.4s"/> what concerns you most about 
  yourself? <break time="0.7s"/> </s> </p> </voice> </speak>`);
  });
```

//not sure why user have to repeat respond twice before moving to next intent

```
app.intent('torespondquestion', (conv, params) => {
 conv.data.toRespondQuestion = params.torespondhere;
 conv.ask(`<speak> <voice gender ="male" variant= "1"> <p> <s> so you said ${conv.data.toRespondQuestion} </s> What experience have you had in that instances? <break time="0.4s"/> <break time="0.4s"/> </p> </voice> </speak>`);
});
```

//not sure why user have to repeat respond twice before moving to next intent

```
app.intent('torespondexperiences', (conv, params) => {
 conv.data.toResondExperiences = params.experienerespond;
 conv.ask(`<speak> <voice gender ="male" variant= "1"> ok <break time="0.8"/> ${conv.data.toResondExperiences} how difficult was it for you to go through it? <break time="0.8"/> </voice> </speak>`);
});
```

//not sure why user have to repeat respond twice before moving to next intent

```
app.intent('ihearyou', (conv, params) => {
 conv.data.hearingYou = params.ihearu;
 conv.ask(`<speak> <voice gender ="male" variant= "1"> i hear you <break time="0.8"/> listening to you describe about your experiences <break time="0.8"/> it sounds like you went through quite a journey <break time="0.8"/> in what ways could you handle the situation differently? </voice> </speak>`);
});
```

Comment: If you can [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55782156/edit) to show the screen shots of the Intents in the Dialogflow UI, it would help us understand the conversation flow and what might be happening. See [Hey Google, I Need Help With My Action](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/hey-google-i-need-help-with-my-action-8cf09714a20d)

Comment: @Prisoner I have added the images for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your intents are using `@sys.any`, I think using a bunch of nested follow-up intents may be creating unnecessary complexity in your project.

Instead, you may want to create a single intent to take in `@sys.any` and create a session variable `conv.data.state`. Your intent handler would then check the current value of `conv.data.state` and respond appropriately, while also setting the state to the next value.